# how to compare the sum score of men to sum score of women to get the count of countries?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say this is my data frame:

```
country     Edition   sports       Athletes        Medal      Gender   Score
Germany     1990    Aquatics  HAJOS, Alfred          gold       M        3
Germany     1990    Aquatics  HIRSCHMANN, Otto       silver     M        2
Germany     1990    Aquatics  DRIVAS, Dimitrios      gold       W        3
Germany     1990    Aquatics  DRIVAS, Dimitrios      silver     W        2
US          2008    Athletics MALOKINIS, Ioannis     gold       M        1
US          2008    Athletics HAJOS, Alfred          silver     M        2
US          2009    Athletics CHASAPIS, Spiridon     gold       W        3
France      2010    Athletics CHOROPHAS, Efstathios  gold       W        3
France      2010    Athletics CHOROPHAS, Efstathios  gold       M        3
France      2010    golf      HAJOS, Alfred          Bronze     M        1
France      2011    golf      ANDREOU, Joannis       silver     W        2
Spain       2011    golf      BURKE, Thomas          gold       M        3
```

I am trying to find for how many countries the sum of men scores is equal to the sum of women scores?
I have tried the following:

`sum_men = df[ df ['Gender']=='M'].groupby ( 'country' )[Score ].sum()` 
`sum_women = df[ df ['Gender']=='W'].groupby ( 'country' )[Score ].sum()`

Now i don't know how to compare this two and filter out no.of countries who have sum of men scores is equal to the sum of women scores.

can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: @moys can you help?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which part isn’t working?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want to leave the ones who are equal or otherwise, but the same logic applies:

```
group = df.groupby(['country', 'Gender'])['Score'].sum().unstack()
not_equal = group[group.M != group.W]
filtered_df = df[df.country.isin(not_equal.index)]
```

Output:

```
   country  Edition     sports               Athletes   Medal Gender  Score  score_sum
7   France     2010  Athletics  CHOROPHAS, Efstathios    gold      W      3          5
8   France     2010  Athletics  CHOROPHAS, Efstathios    gold      M      3          4
9   France     2010       golf          HAJOS, Alfred  Bronze      M      1          4
10  France     2011       golf       ANDREOU, Joannis  silver      W      2          5
11   Spain     2011       golf          BURKE, Thomas    gold      M      3          3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
sum_men = df[df['Gender']=='M'].groupby ('Country' )['Score'].sum().reset_index() #watch the reset_index()
sum_women = df[df['Gender']=='W'].groupby ('Country' )['Score'].sum().reset_index()
new_df = sum_men.merge(sum_women, on="Country")
new_df['diff'] = new_df['Score_x'] - new_df['Score_y']
new_df

   Country  Score_x  Score_y  diff
0   France        4        5    -1
1  Germany        5        5     0
2       US        3        3     0

print(new_df[new_df['diff']==0])

Country  Score_x  Score_y  diff
1  Germany        5        5     0
2       US        3        3     0
```

Comment: you are awesome! but can we do it using pandas pivot table?

Comment: Hey! You can do something like this:
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, columns=['Country', 'Gender'], values = ['Score'],     aggfunc='sum').unstack()

    print(pivot[pivot.M == pivot.W]) #this will be similar to the past result